# How to check for class attribute initialization with a decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

Consider the following code.

```py
def check(data):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if data not in ["toto", "tata"]:
                raise ValueError("Wrong argument")
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator


class Foo:
    
    @check
    def __init__(data):
        self.data = data
         
         
Foo(data="t")
```

I would like to decorate the `__init__` function of a class, but I get an exception :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 19, in <module>
TypeError: decorator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'
```

Comment: Do you want to decorate the class or the `__init__` method?

Comment: Okay…? What have you tried in terms of making this a decorator and where are you stuck?

Comment: I would like to decorate the `__init__` method. I know how to decorate a simple function but I don't know to decorate a class function.

Comment: There's no fundamental difference. What have you tried, what problem did you run into?

Comment: Where should I put the decorator ? In top of the definition of the class or in top of the `__init__` ? What are best practices ? How to decorate a function with parameters ? That are the main problems I am running into :/

Comment: Just on top of the function: `@my_deco def __init__(self, data): ...`. Update your question with a sample, and we can tell you where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up which function receives what. `check` is the decorator which receives *the function* you're decorating, not `data`. `wrapper` is the function which will receive `data`. You don't need the third function in there. So:

```
def check(function):
    def wrapper(self, data):
        if data not in ["toto", "tata"]:
            raise ValueError("Wrong argument")

        return function(self, data)

    return wrapper
```

Comment: Oh I see. Can you give me some words for the reasons why `self` is used outside the definition of the class ?

Comment: Because `wrapper` will replace `__init__`. The class will have the `wrapper` function in place of `__init__`. So it will receive a `self` argument and must accept it and pass it on to the actual `function`/`__init__`.